# Mocking JWT in pytest fails as unauthorized

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Im trying to write PyTests against a few endpoints in flask just to assert some status codes coming back and I have mocked the JWT using the mock package

So I have imported the package and set up the test:

```py
import pytest
from . import app
from mock import patch


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return app.test_client()


def test_index(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Success: TAGR API' in response.data


@patch("flask_jwt_extended.verify_jwt_in_request")
def test_sites(mock_verify, client):
    response = client.get('/sites/get')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

the endpoint im testing againt is:

```py
@sites_blueprint.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def get_all():
    sites = Sites.query.all()
    return jsonify({
        "data": sites_schema.dump(sites),
        "message": "Success: Sites fetched successfully",
        "status": 200
    }), 200
```

and the error I get is:

```
mock_verify = <MagicMock name='verify_jwt_in_request' id='2347808021328'>, client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'application'>>

    @patch("flask_jwt_extended.verify_jwt_in_request")
    def test_sites(mock_verify, client):
        response = client.get('/sites/get')
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 401 == 200
E        +  where 401 = <WrapperTestResponse streamed [401 UNAUTHORIZED]>.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

`verify_jwt_in_request` is it importable from `flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators`.

Modified code with proper path decorator is as below:

```
@patch('flask_jwt_extended.view_decorators.verify_jwt_in_request')
def test_sites(mock_verify, client):
    response = client.get('/sites/get')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```